# Program to obtain music metadata

Tags: mp3, metadata-editor

What happened is that while renaming a song through MusicBee, my computer froze. For some reason after power cycling the machine it had renamed all 30GBs of music in the playlist to the same name. Since the machine was power cycled, no simple CTRL+Z will fix this. I am wondering if there is a good program out there for free or cheap that can go through and fix all of the song names.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Do you have a recent restore point?

Comment: I am on windows 7, all my music on an external though. I have a backup of the music but that backup is missing 3000 songs worth of ratings

Answer (score 1):

in such cases [**foobar2000**](http://www.foobar2000.org/) rules, it's free, very easy to edit metadata (for one file or more simultaneously ), and contains a media player.

Comment: But can it retrieve the song names from online?

Comment: hmm i haven't tried it, but there is a plugin that can do, http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_musicbrainz

as they mentioned it downloads them from MusicBrainz

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot on my lunch break.